# Pixelated render in cycle when camera clipping higher

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

i try build up our solar system with accurate proportions.[image]

And for a better view of the scene i increased the clipping range of the viewport to 100000

[image]

But now when i texturing my saturn, some strange pixelated effects appear

[image]

and when i decrease the clipping to 1000 back it looks normal

[image]

So i am a bit confused. What do i am wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. You're not doing anything wrong. Your project is simply clipping the boundaries of Blender floating point precision of depth. (Pun intended.) But could it be possible to reduce the depth range by increasing the clipping **Start** to a much higher value? Surely 10 couldn't be that harmful given the scale of your scene.

Comment: Hi Leander, tried it out with start increased to 10 but nothing better https://imgur.com/a/U35pBYw

Comment: Oh, I must be mistaken. Have you tried rendering it (F12) through a camera, with those clipping values?

Comment: What if you scaled all the distances down? I mean, real proportions might really be way too much, given a float might have 8? 16? 24 bytes? It reaches a limit, as you can see :-)

Comment: @Ignatiamus More like more like 23 (32bit) or 52 (64bit)  ***bits***. However, relatively scaling **everything** down will not change anything, since the relative distances will remain the same.

Comment: @Leander now rendered it and it looks as expected https://imgur.com/a/nLbzPeZ thanks

Comment: I advise you to make entirely miniature model. The final render will look exactly the same as the big one, but it's easier to work with.

Comment: @Leander uh… alright, yes. :-)

Comment: @KaarelParve That's what I meant, yeah. And I thought that you won't reach the floating point range limit that fast, but was probably mistaken.